# How to save the current goal / subgoal as an `assert` lemma

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

During a proof, I come to a situation where the current goal/subgoal turned out to be useful in a later stage of the same theorem.

Is there a tactic to "save" the current goal as a lemma as if the current goal is `assert`ed?

Of course, I can copy&paste to  `assert` the goal explicitly, or write a separate Lemma before the current theorem. But I am just curious if shortcuts exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such feature in `Coq`, and neither `CoqIDE` nor `ProofGeneral` seems to provide one.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this answer for future reference.

I don't know since when it exists, but maybe the [abstract](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ltac.html#coq:tacn.abstract) tactic could help.
It allows you to name a part of the proof and re-use it later, even if you are in a different sub-goal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Proof General, you can install a [company-coq](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/company-coq) extension which provides this functionality. It is bound the `C-c C-a C-x` key sequence.